# Consequences of Langlands functoriality conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, l-functions, langlands-conjectures, selberg-class

I would like to know whether Langlands' functoriality conjecture implies that the Selberg class coincides with the class of automorphic L-functions and, if so, whether this class is closed under Rankin-Selberg convolution or not.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has been answered in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207306/what-is-exactly-the-difference-between-the-selberg-class-and-the-set-of-artin-l

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78247/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Langlands functoriality conjecture implies that automorphic $L$-functions belong to the Selberg class, but not the other way (i.e. the other direction is not known to follow from this conjecture). Regarding to Rankin-Selberg convolutions, I don't think that this operation has been defined precisely for the Selberg class. There is a subtlety at the ramified primes: one usually refers to the algebraic classification of the underlying local representations, which is itself part of the Langlands program.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this operation has been defined for the Selberg class in Murty, M. Ram and Zaharescu, Alexandru (2002), ”Explicit for-
mulas for the pair correlation of zeros of functions in the Selberg class”,
Forum Math. 14 (2002), no. 1, pp. 65-83.

Comment: may I send you a copy of the latest version of an article of mine dealing with such issues? You can join me at sylvainjul'at'gmail'dot'com.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: I don't have any free time to join your project, sorry about this. If your paper gets published, I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: You can read it there: http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?43,1210447